# Add a label with GMAIL API with python

Tags: python, api, gmail

I'm trying here to add labels on with gmail api
for this, i used the example here : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify#try-it
the problem is, when I want to put my own label , i get a 400 from the server

```
def add_label_to_email(service, user_id, msg_id, msg_labels):
"""Modify the Labels on the given Message.

Args:
service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
msg_id: The id of the message required.
msg_labels: The change in labels.

Returns:
Modified message, containing updated labelIds, id and threadId.
"""
try:
    message = service.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id,
                                                id=msg_id,
                                                body=msg_labels).execute()

    label_ids = message['labelIds']

    logging.debug('Message ID: %s - With Label IDs %s' % (msg_id, label_ids))
    return message
except errors.HttpError, error:
    logging.debug('An error occurred: %s' % error)


def create_message_label():
"""Create object to update labels.

Returns:
A label update object.
"""
return {'removeLabelIds': [], 'addLabelIds': ['my_label']}
```

the error message :

```
DEBUG    2017-07-17 08:25:36,072 api_gmail.py:178] An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/15d4e47f393487c2/modify?alt=json returned "Invalid label: my_label">
```

it's working with the example :

```
def CreateMsgLabels():
  """Create object to update labels.

  Returns:
    A label update object.
  """
  return {'removeLabelIds': [], 'addLabelIds': ['UNREAD', 'INBOX', 'Label_2']}
```

I don't understand how does it works, if anyone can help ?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: maybe if the label is not created before, it throw me an error ?

Comment: That might be so, however you say that it works with the example from the API documentation, do your user already have a "Label_2" created?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a confusion between labelId and labelName. The labelId user passed to the gmail api is actually the gmail label field *name* and not id.

The true label ID can be found by first calling the api to request all labels:

```
labelsList = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
print(labelsList)
```

The labelsList var I believe is a dict type and dispenses the 'id' and 'name' for each label. The above code can then be used by calling the api with the updated labelId.

User likely had unfortunate coincidence that there was already a label with the id set to 'Label_2'. Hope this helps anyone else.